# Does amazon AWS (EC2/S3) have port 2195 enabled?

Tags: iphone, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, push-notification

Clearly its not on their FAQ. Nor can I find it on the web. Any one with an account can test the following for me?

```
telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

I would start using their free tier and move on to the paid service later.

regards

mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, if you own an ec2 instance you have full control over ports, i.e you decide what you want open.

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1697

note outbound ports are open (aws firewall only blocks incoming)

the only cavet is if you run a firewall on the ec2 instance well (iptables/windows firewall), you would then need to configure the outbound rule.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think it looks right. I am trying out the instance now. If what you said is indeed correct, I will mark it as correct answer. Just wanted to give a heads-up that I didn't forget about tagging the answer as right.